# How to check email id is exist or not before registration in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, register

I am new to magento.I want to check the user provide email is already exist or not on **custom registration page**. I tried this with *java script* (apply in same file)but it shows html content in response text.

Answer (score 7):

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($customer_email);

if($customer->getId())
{
  "Customer Exist";
}
```

You can check this by server side and send status in response.

Comment: hi its working fine but reloading page .Is it possible to check this without reloading page?

Comment: For that you can do it two ways.
1. Do AJAX call and check it at server side and get the status in response on form submission.
2. Create java-script array of all email ids in system and check email exist in array or not after submit the form.

Comment: how?can you please give some working example?

Answer (score 1):

```
$email ="xyz@gmail.com";
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())->loadByEmail($email);
if($customer->getId()){
    echo "customer exists";
}else{
 echo "customer doesn't exists";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have three options: Y
ou could query to API (SOAP or REST) to check for existing customer with given e-mail,

you could write a custom extension that provides this functionality through JavaScript and an additional URL to query, search for existing extensions that incorporate this function.

But: The check for existing e-mail is a built-in function, although not client-side only in most of the templates available.

Answer (score 0):

```
$customerObj = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
        $customerObj->setWebsiteId($website->getId());
        $customerObj->loadByEmail($customer['email']);
        if ($customerObj->getId()) {
          $message = "duplicate found" ;
          return $message;
       }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome on Magento SE. Code-only answers are discouraged here. Could you please provide a small explanation for your code?